# I cannot hold the list item after clicked

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I am new to React. I am working on a to-do list right now.

My problem is that I want to be able to select one item from the list and when I clicked the completed button, the item should be lined through. The code can draw only one item which is at the beginning. However, I want to draw any item I want.

Here is my code:

```
const drawEl = (e) => {
    const getList = document.getElementById("listItems")
    const getCompButton = document.getElementById("completed")
    
    if (e.target === getCompButton) {
      getList.style.color = "grey"
      getList.style.textDecoration = "line-through"
    }
  }

   
  return (
    <div id="container">
      <h1>todos</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} >
        <input placeholder="What needs to be done?" name="todo" value={form.todo} onChange={handleChange} />
        <List forCurrentList={currentList}  />
        
        <div id="btns"> 
            
            <button>Add</button>
            <button type="button">All</button>
            <button type="button">Active</button>
            <button type="button" id="completed" onClick={drawEl} 
            >Completed</button>
          
          </div>
        
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;


function List({ forCurrentList }) {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {forCurrentList.map((item, index) => (
          <li id="listItems" key={index}>{item.todo}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default List
```

All answers will be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Code such as `document.getElementById` is JavaScript code. In your entire project - there should be only 1 of such line to get a DOM element so react would know where to go in. Besides that - such code should NOT exist. If you want to use plain JavaScript - then use JavaScript. But if you're using react - use react. Things like this what create a lot of issues/bugs in apps. Solve this and the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Then, I suppose I will be using a state hook in that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same id ("listItems") – that's totally wrong in terms of html, and getElementById(...) returns only the first matching element (and that's your job – to guarantee that there is only one).
Lith's comment is absolutely correct – your must not use "vanilla JS DOM-functions" like getElementById – use React stuff like useRef hooks and so on – and you'll avoid such mistakes :)